# One Regular Expression to validate US and Canada ZIP / Postal Code

Tags: regex

I am developing a stationery program. Customers have choice to pick their region either US or Canada. When they enter address they have to enter ZIP/Postal code. I am trying to validate field but I cannot use reg exp either for US or Canada. I require a regular expression that validates for both country zip code.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Not knowing what language you're using, I will not use any abbreviations for character classes:

```
^[0-9]{5}$|^[A-Z][0-9][A-Z] ?[0-9][A-Z][0-9]$
```

Depending on your language, you might be able to abbreviate this to

```
^([0-9]{5}|[A-Z][0-9][A-Z] ?[0-9][A-Z][0-9])$
```

or

```
^(\d{5}|[A-Z]\d[A-Z] ?\d[A-Z]\d)$
```

To support ZIP+4:

```
^(\d{5}(-\d{4})?|[A-Z]\d[A-Z] ?\d[A-Z]\d)$
```

And if you want to get really picky about your Canada codes:

```
^(\d{5}(-\d{4})?|[A-CEGHJ-NPRSTVXY]\d[A-CEGHJ-NPRSTV-Z] ?\d[A-CEGHJ-NPRSTV-Z]\d)$
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how Canadian postal codes work, but should this take lower case letters too?

Comment: I believe not.  [Postal codes in Canada](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postal_codes_in_Canada)

Comment: This also doesn't support US +4 zip codes. I.e. 12345-6789

Answer (score 2):

Furthering the answer above you could add (?i) to the beginning of the regex to make is case insensitive.  So it would look like this:

```
^(?i)(\d{5}(-\d{4})?|[A-CEGHJ-NPRSTVXY]\d[A-CEGHJ-NPRSTV-Z] ?\d[A-CEGHJ-NPRSTV-Z]\d)$
```

Comment: Except that that is language dependent (and wouldn't work in the languages *I* code in; OP doesn't say what language *they* are using).

Comment: For academic purposes, what language is that?  The language I am using, that this works in, is asp.net/c#.

Comment: I was thinking Javascript, where you would make a regex case insensitive by applying a flag that isn't part of the pattern itself (it's an extra param when creating a regex object).

Comment: Reading the comments on the first answer you'll notice that lowercase letters are actually not allowed in Canadian postal codes.  So aside from the fact that `(?i)` is non-standard, it's also not correct for this question.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me. Tested with both American Zip Code and Canadian Postal Code.

```
^((\d{5}-\d{4})|(\d{5})|([A-Z|a-z]\d[A-Z|a-z]\d[A-Z|a-z]\d))$
```